# Undefined reference building ncurses on cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, ncurses

Windows XP:

I ultimately wanted to install DDD (the debugger). Its not available in binary form for Windows. When I got its source and tried to configure it, it complained that no term caps library was present. So I acquire ncurses and got this after a mostly successfull build using Cygwin Terminal:

```
../lib/libncurses.a(lib_ttyflags.o)(.text+0x41):lib_ttyflags.c: undefined reference to `_nc_mingw_ioctl'
../lib/libncurses.a(lib_ttyflags.o)(.text+0xd1):lib_ttyflags.c: undefined reference to `_nc_mingw_ioctl'
```

Comment: Why are you building ncurses from source?  It's available as part of Cygwin.

Comment: `ddd` is also available in Cygwin.  I don't think it's installed by default, but you can install it via `setup.exe`.

Comment: Do I need to run the Cygwin install again?

Answer (score 6):

It works for me when I do this:

```
configure --enable-term-driver --enable-sp-funcs
make
```

The --enable-term-driver was needed for "mingw" (I tested on msys, but this should work equally well on cygwin), and --enable-term-driver requires --enable-sp-funcs.

> ```
>           --enable-sp-funcs
>                   compile-in  support  for  extended  functions which
>                   accept  a  SCREEN  pointer,  reducing  the need for
>                   juggling  the  global  SP  value  with set_term and
>                   delscreen.
>
>           --enable-term-driver
>                   compile  with  terminal-driver. That is used in the
>                   MinGW  port,  and (being somewhat more complicated)
>                   is  an experimental alternative to the conventional
>                   termlib   internals.  Currently,  it  requires  the
>                   sp-funcs feature to be enabled.
> ```

See here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2011-02/msg00020.html