# how to install ncurses on windows

Tags: gcc, ncurses

How can I make ncurses work on my windows? I've tried every way to make it work but my gcc compiler doesn't recognize it, it's installed correctly in the directory
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\ncurses
I installed through MSYS2. Can someone help me?

I tried to compile my code as follows:
gcc test.c -o test -IC:\msys64\mingw64\include
it returned me the error in the compiler, I tried to run it with another command:
gcc test.c -o test -I C:\msys64\mingw64\include -L C:\msys64\mingw64\lib -lncurses
It didn't work either, I don't know what to do.

the specific error:
test.c:1:10: fatal error: ncurses.h: No such file or directory
1 | #include <ncurses.h>
| ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
I'm using vscode, but even in the windows terminal the same problem occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference building ncurses on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956455/undefined-reference-building-ncurses-on-cygwin)

Comment: I had the same proplem and found this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656787/cannot-static-link-ncurses-with-mingw

`gcc test.c -o test -I C:\msys64\mingw64\include -L C:\msys64\mingw64\lib -lncurses  -DNCURSES_STATIC`  might do the trick, maybe even without  -L C:\msys64\mingw64\lib

Answer (score 3):

With a default installation of msys2 MingW64 used by VS Code, ncurses is basically present, but the correct include and link is not self-evident.

Here is a very simple ncurses-helloworld.cpp:

```cpp
#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // init screen and sets up screen
    initscr();
    // print to screen
    printw("Hello World");
    // refreshes the screen
    refresh();
    // pause the screen output
    getch();
    // deallocates memory and ends ncurses
    // endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Of course you can set the include-paths in configurations of e.g. `vscode` or the commandline of the compiler or in the makefile or wherever so that a

```cpp
#include <ncurses.h>
```

works, but in the meantime I got used to just include everything that is in the subdirectories of
`C:\msys64\mingw64\include` in the form
`#include <directory name/filename.h>` - this works very easily, without any further configuration settings, for everything that can be installed directly via `pacman` with the msys packages.

To use this to link the library of ncurses correctly, use the following:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -lncurses -DNCURSES_STATIC
```

or

```
gcc test.c -o test.exe -lncurses -DNCURSES_STATIC
```

for pure c-programs.

An explanation was given in a comment by Brecht Sanders on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656787/cannot-static-link-ncurses-with-mingw), which had led the OP at the time to the appropriate solution:

"The header defines `__declspec(dllexport)` unless `NCURSES_STATIC` is defined, so adding `-DNCURSES_STATIC` as a compile option fixes everything."

Comment: I know I'm mainly referring to solutions that have already been posted here on StackOverflow in other places, but still, it's hard to find the solution when you encounter this problem.
I think the current question is the right one to post a comprehensive answer that can be easily found.

Since this is a recurring issue, the question deserves a summary and coherent answer for once. 

Perhaps the title should be changed to
`how to use ncurses on windows`, as it is definitely not about the "installation" of ncurses, but about the usage, the correct #include and linker statements for gcc.

Comment: Thanks a lot man I've been searching for this

Answer (score 0):

`g++ test.c -o test.exe -lncursesw`

this worked for me

I installed ncurses using MSYS on windows 10 using
 `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-ncurses` command