# lncurses in vs code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, ncurses

please help me to add lncurses to visual studio when I want translate code then get this error

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lncursec
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I install ubuntu on windows and download lncurses but I dont know how to add it on the vscode, I try to download pdcurses from internet and add it to folder when I have vs code but it still didnt work

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us your `tasks.json` file. And copy-paste (as text) the ***full*** and ***complete*** build log into the question.

Comment: The error message mentions `-lncursec` but it should be `-lncurses`.

Comment: "I install ubuntu on windows and download lncurses" This doesn't sound right. Are you trying to use ncurses from your Ubuntu installation to create a Windows program? It won't work. "I try to download pdcurses from internet and add it to folder when I have vs code but it still didnt work" We cannot help you without seeing what exactly you tried to do and which error messages you've got.

Comment: You may also want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75556484/how-to-install-ncurses-on-windows).